# I cant only attach one thread created by select SQL

Tags: mysql

I use gdb to debug mysql as following steps:

1. run `ps aux | grep mysqld` to get pid and use `gdb attach pid` to debug mysql.
2. enter `bt` and can see following messages:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f020bb18bcf in __GI___poll (fds=0x55ac789dd8d0, nfds=2, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
29      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c: no such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f020bb18bcf in __GI___poll (fds=0x55ac789dd8d0, nfds=2, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x000055ac72918b1f in Mysqld_socket_listener::listen_for_connection_event() ()
#2  0x000055ac726f1178 in mysqld_main(int, char**) ()
#3  0x00007f020ba29d90 in __libc_start_call_main (main=main@entry=0x55ac726969f0 <main>, argc=argc@entry=1,
    argv=argv@entry=0x7fffc26c56f8) at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#4  0x00007f020ba29e40 in __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x55ac726969f0 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffc26c56f8,
    init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffc26c56e8)
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
#5  0x000055ac726c30b5 in _start ()
```

I dont know if the message `no such file or directory.` is problem.

3. enter `b row_sel_step` to add breakpoint at function `row_sel_step` and enter `c` to continue process.
4. I enter `select * from t1;` in another window where a connection has been created to `mysqld`.

---

#### Problems

I stop at breakpoint function called `row_sel_step`. But when I enter `n` in gdb, I see messages:

`[Switching to Thread 0x7f01d9ffb640 (LWP 1579)]` and `Thread 23 "ib_dict_stats" hit Breakpoint 1, 0x000055ac73471f88 in row_sel_step(que_thr_t*) ()`.

It means that I **dont only** attach one thread craeted by `select SQL`.

---

#### Wants

I want `gdb` can stop at breakpoint function called `row_sel_step`, and this gdb can **only** attach one thread created by `select SQL`.

I want to know which function a `select SQL` will enter, so I want to **only** attach one thread created by `select SQL`, not other threads like: `ib_dict_stats` thread, etc.

---

###### I also try another way:

1. enter `gdb --args ./mysqld`.
2. enter `b row_sel_step` to stop at function.
3. enter `r` to run.
4. In another window where connection has been created, I enter `select * from t1;`. This SQL returns results **immediately** and `gdb` dont stop.

---

Can you give me some tips? Thank you very much.

Comment: why not add it at that position and try it

Answer (score 0):

#### Done

Before I enter `select * from t1;`,  I enter `flush tables;` to clear cache.  The `gdb` will stop at the function `row_sel_step` and more than once. (I **guess** the reason for more than once is index page retrieval)  So, I can **guess** that only retrieving records from disk file, not from buffer pool, can enter function `row_sel_step`.  If I am wrong, please tell me, please.

Thanks! :)

---

##### 2024.3.18 edit

The `show create table qwe\G` like following:

```
mysql> show create table qwe\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: qwe
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `qwe` (
  `a` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

1. I add two breakpoints at `row_sel_step` function and `row_search_mvcc` function.

   2.1. I enter `select b from qwe;` **immediately after** entering 'flush tables;', I will enter `row_search_mvcc` function and `row_sel_step` function.

   2.2. I enter `select b from qwe;` without entering `flush tables;`, I will enter `row_search_mvcc` function, **not** `row_sel_step` function.

`flush tables` will flush cache, so I must get page from disk through `row_search_mvcc` function firstly.

If I am wrong, please tell me, please.

Thanks! :)